# How can I get the context root of an application using a wsadmin jython script with -conntype NONE in WAS

Tags: get, jython, ibm-was, wsadmin, contextroot

I am trying to create a script that prints out the web URLs of certain commonly used applications, but am having difficulty finding a wsadmin command that will get the web context root for an application.

I am aware that `AdminApp.view(app, '-CtxRootForWebMod')` contains that information, but am wondering if there is a call that will return only the context root.

Answer (score 1):

I use taskinfo to get mapping details:

```
print AdminApp.taskinfo('<filename>', '-CtxRootForWebMod')
```